# Find $3^{2015} + 7^{2015}\bmod50$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Find the remainder when $3^{2015} + 7^{2015}$ is divided by $50$.

I've thought about modular arithmetic, but I'm not sure how to exactly use it here.

Comment: prove that the remainder is zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below let $\, m=50,\ a=3,\ b = 7\,$ and $\,n = 2015/5 = 403$

${\rm mod}\ m\!:\  \begin{align}\color{#0a0}{a^{\large 5} \equiv -b}\\ \color{#c00}{b^{\large 5} \equiv\, b}\ \ \,\end{align}$ $\Rightarrow\, \color{#0a0}a^{\large \color{#0a0}5n}\!+\color{#c00}b^{\large \color{#c00}5n} \equiv\, (\color{#0a0}{-b})^{\large n}\! + \color{#c00}b^{\large n} \equiv -b^{\large n}+b^{\large n}\equiv 0\ $ if $\,n\,$ is odd.

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$
3^{2015}+7^{2015}=(3^5)^{403}+(7^5)^{403}
$$
is divisible (because $403$ is odd) by $3^5+7^5$ which is $17050$.

Answer (score 1):

- First you can use : $3^{20}\equiv 7^{20}\equiv 1 \mod 50$
- You will have as remainder $3^{15}+7^{15}$ and you know that $7^2\equiv -1 \mod 50$ and $3^{15}\equiv 7 \mod 50$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $3^5=243\equiv -7\bmod 50$ and $(-7)^2=7^2\equiv -1\bmod 50$

Then $$3^{2015}+7^{2015}\equiv  (-1)^{201}\cdot-7+(-1)^{1007}\cdot 7\equiv 0$$

Comment: Why did you do (-7)^2 mod 50? Also, could you explain the 2nd part of your answer (after "Then")?

Comment: @QuantumJuker $(-7)^2=49\equiv -1 \bmod 50$. From this we have $3^{10}=(3^5)^2 \equiv -1$ so that $3^{2015}=3^{2010}\cdot 3^5\equiv (-1)^{201}\cdot (-7)$. Finally $7^{2015}=7^{2014}\cdot 7=(7^2)^{1007}\cdot 7\equiv (-1)^{1007}\cdot 7$. The two terms have numerical value $7$ bit different signs, so the sum is zero. It is a bit cumbersome to write all the reductions down - but I put the answer as I did, because that is how I did it in my head - each of the individual pieces is easy if you get $7^2=49$ and $3^5=243$ - I think powers of $3$ are not so well known as powers of $2$.

Answer (score 0):

**Method** $\#1:$

$$3^{2n+1}+7^{2n+1}=(10-7)^{2n+1}+7^{2n+1}\equiv\binom{2n+1}110\cdot7^{2n}\pmod{50}\equiv7^{2n}(2n+1)10$$

It will be $\equiv0\pmod{50}$
$\iff5|2n+1\iff2n\equiv-1\pmod5\equiv-1+5\iff n\equiv2\pmod5$

---

**Method** $\#2:$
$$3^{2n+1}=3(10-1)^n$$

Using Binomial Expansion,
$$3^{2n+1}\equiv3[(-1)^n+\binom n110(-1)^{n-1}]\pmod{50}\equiv(-1)^n[3-30n]$$

$$7^{2n+1}=7(50-1)^n\equiv7(-1)^n\pmod{50}$$

$$3^{2n+1}+7^{2n+1}\equiv(-1)^n[10-30n]\pmod{50}\equiv0$$

if $50|(10-30n)\iff5|(1-3n)\iff3n\equiv1\pmod5\equiv1+5\iff n\equiv2\pmod5$

---

Both method implies

$n=5m+2\iff2n+1=2(5m+2)+1=5(2m+1)$ where $m$ is any integer

Comment: Great detailed answer. I understand how you used the Binomial Theorem (is that right?) to get 7^2n * (2n + 1) * 10. From there, can you explain how you arrived at 0 for an answer?

Comment: @QuantumJuker, By method $\#1,$ if $5|2n+1,50$ will divide $3^{2n+1}+7^{2n+1}$ and by method $\#2,$ we need $5|1-3n$